# PHPUnit: Testing RestFul API with die response

Tags: php, json, api, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am trying to PHPUnit test an action in my ZF2 project.

The APIs return a JSON string using `die($jsonObject)`.

This causes the PHPUnit test to stop processing and just die a JSON response.

```
public function testStartupAction() {

    $this->dispatch('/api/v3/startup', "POST", array());

    $this->assertJson('{"status":false,"message":"Please enter the UID","data":null}');

}
```

`assetJson` method is never reached.

PHPUnit output:

```
PHPUnit 4.7.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
..{"status":false,"message":"Please enter the UID","data":null}
```

How can the PHPUnit continue on testing so I'd get a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest trying to find the solution in rewriting your the code that returns your JSON string inside your controller. Using `die` to return a response object is not the way to go.

An example on how to return JSON from your controller action could be as simple as:

```
$model = new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel($data);
return $model
```

Where $data is your data array. The result will be automatically changed to a JSON string.

This will also solve your testing issues.